# Path is not a legal form on downloading .xls file on sharepoint

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, console

Hi i have this c# console application that needs to download the file from the sharepoint to my local computer, and i only have the access to the file [image], here's the code i've try

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string username = "**.**.**.*@***.com";
            const string password ="*****";
            const string url = "https://name.sharepoint.com/";
            var securedPassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);
            DownloadFile(url, credentials, "personal/thomas_heinecke_nexperia_com/Documents/Reporting/ONE_Complaints_Actions/ONE_Complaints_Actions_Report.xlsx");

        }

        private static void DownloadFile(string webUrl, ICredentials credentials, string fileRelativeUrl)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
                client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
                client.Credentials = credentials;
                client.DownloadFile(webUrl, fileRelativeUrl); <---Failed here 
            }
        }
```

and the error prompt is

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: An exception occurred during a WebClient request
```

with inner exception of `{"The path is not of a legal form."}`
the only i have is the link, is it possible to download through that link
What i'm doing wrong ?
Hope someone help me out with this

**update**

here's the error i'm facing now `{"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Users\\nx011116\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication3\\ConsoleApplication3\\bin\\Debug\\personal\\thomas_heinecke_nexperia_com\\Documents\\Reporting\\ONE_Complaints_Actions\\ONE_Complaints_Actions_Report.xlsx'."}`
i updated my code above

Comment: That error is a file path, not a web url. It's the result of using your relative path as being relative to your current (file system path). Step through the program and see where it's coming from

Comment: umm, how can i set the path of the file to download folder?

Comment: oww thankyou i did not even realize that now its solve